# How to fix these errors: C2146 & C4430 (in c++)

Tags: c++

So, my teacher gave the class this code, but I'm having trouble running it.
The errors I get are C2146 & C4430. I tried messing around by adding includes to header files, but I'm still not sure what the problem is.

I've commented the code below where the errors were indicated by the compiler.

assoc.h file

```
template<class T> class assoc {
 public:

  struct pair {
    string key;   //error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'key'
    T      value; 
    pair  *next;  


    pair() : key(), value(), next(NULL) {}

    pair( const string& key, T value, pair* next = NULL ) //error c4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: c++ does not suport default - int
      : key(key), value(value), next(next) {}
  };

private:
  pair * table;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `string` type is not defined. You need to import it from the `std` namespace:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
```

Of course you could also import everything from the namespace using `using namespace std;` but that's usually a bad idea - for thing that are not as widespread as `string` it's better to use the qualified name (e.g. `std::pair`). Your code is actually a great example for this, with `using namespace std` your `pair` would collide with the one from `std`.

Comment: i didn't know about the std::string. Thanks!